# Read an image from other host

Tags: java, swing, file, url, javax.imageio

I'm trying to read an image from another host but I failed. Here is what I tried:

```
ImageIO.read(new File("http://199.231.95.45:8081/images/bg.png"));
```

How can I do that? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `File` is a reference to a local file on the file system (or network drive), it does not relate to a resource on web server.

Use `URL` instead

```
ImageIO.read(new URL("http://199.231.95.45:8081/images/bg.png"));
```

Comment: Thanks it's working! for some reasons I have to wait 10 minutes to accept your answer -.-